# Cómo corregir el error System.Xml.XmlException: ''http' is an unexpected token?

Tags: c#, webservice

Estoy haciendo un static XmlDocument para generar mi Xml manualmente, pero cuando hago el `xdoc.LoadXml`   me salta el sigueinte error:

> System.Xml.XmlException: ''http' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''. Line 1, position 33.'

```
  private static XmlDocument GetSoapString(string cuit)
    {
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        string direccion = "http://direccion.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";

        string soapString = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=" + direccion + " xmlns:urn=" + "urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style" + ">" +
        " <soapenv:Header/>" +
                  " <soapenv:Body>                             " +
                  "    <urn:ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetList>         " +
                  "       <Customerid>" + cuit + "</Customerid>" +
                  "       <PedidoCli ></ PedidoCli>            " +
                  "       <PedidoSap></PedidoSap>            " + +
                  "       <TFacturaMat>                        " +
                  "          <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->  " +
                  "          <item>                            " +
                  "             <Vbeln></Vbeln>              " +
                  "             <Posnr></Posnr>              " +
                  "             <Matnr></Matnr>              " +
                  "          </item>                           " +
                  "       </TFacturaMat>                       " +
                  "       <!--Optional:-->                      " +
                  "       <TInvoices>                          " +
                  "          <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->  " +
                  "          <item>                            " +
                  "             <FacturaPdf></FacturaPdf>    " +
                  "             <FacturaSap></FacturaSap>    " +
                  "             <FacturaExt></FacturaExt>    " +
                               "<Nombre></Nombre>" +
                            "</item>" +
                         "</TInvoices>" +
                         "<!--Optional:-->" +
                      "</urn:ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetList>" +
                   "</soapenv:Body>" +
               " </soapenv:Envelope>";

        xdoc.LoadXml(soapString); //aca está el error

        return xdoc;
    }
```

Por lo que entendi estoy armando mal el Xml y que debo hacer o usar un Namespace, estoy en lo correcto?

Answer (score 3):

creo que la dirección http tiene que ir entre comillas simples:

```
"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='" + direccion + "' xmlns:urn=" + "urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style" + ">"
```